# Captcha on C2DM

Tags: android, push, captcha, android-c2dm

I've been implementing the server side of Google's c2dm.

I have a problem when requesting the ClientToken from https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin . I'm returned a 403 Captcha Challenge. This is as the api specifies, but it then the api further specifies that the Captcha should be shown to the current user.

How are you supposed to forward the Captcha, when the code is server based?

Comment: The answer is: Don't request it too frequently and cross your fingers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the reason you got the 403 Captcha is because you have sent the Auth request too frequently, it is better if you do the client authenticate once and store the Authcode persistently, and use that single Authcode until you catch the INVALID_SENDER error, then, just authenticate again and update the old Authcode,

Comment: Following that, should I expect never to get the captcha challenge, or just less frequently?

Comment: In my case, I have never got any captcha so far, what i did is that i setup a cron job to schedule the authentication within certain mount of time.

Comment: Right, but even being an unlikely case, don't you do anything in the case it arises?